# How to modify a global array inside a multithreaded function

Tags: .net, windows, multithreading, function, powershell

I am trying to add a value to a global array inside a function. The function call is multithreaded and several instances of the function are called instantaneously

Each thread modifies the array but overwrites data written to it by other threads.

My code is below:

```
Function QuickPing { 

    param ($LastByte) 
    $P = New-Object -TypeName "System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping" 
    if(($P.Send("200.200.200.$LastByte")).status -eq "success"){
        echo "this one responded 200.200.200.$LastByte"
        $global:alive+="200.200.200.$LastByte" 
        $global:alive
    }
} 
$global:alive = @()


1..255 | Start-Parallel -Command QuickPing -MaxThreads 500 

write-host $alive
```

and the output is below:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> E:\scripts_during_phase2\ping_array.ps1
this one responded 200.200.200.1
200.200.200.1
this one responded 200.200.200.17
200.200.200.17
this one responded 200.200.200.254
200.200.200.254


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $alive

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

As can be seen above the value in $alive array is overwritten everytime that function is called.

How do i ensure that `$alive` contains `200.200.200.1,200.200.200.17,200.200.200.254` when the `write-host $alive` command is run

Comment: [`Start-Parallel`](https://jamesone111.wordpress.com/2016/12/06/do-the-job-100-times-faster-with-parallel-processing-in-powershell/) appears to be custom module based on [`RunspaceFactory Class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspacefactory?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0). There is actually an explicit note from the design `*Remember that RunSpaces don’t share anything*`, which is not generaly true for RunSpaces, as you can share information with a `SessionStateProxy Class` but that is apparently not implemented in this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use a lock.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)

This will ensure that only one thread has access to the array at a time

Comment: And how do you share the state of the lock? This is basically a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22) solution unless you further elaborate on how to implemented this for this question.